# Removing Dupicates in rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I needed a query to remove the duplicates from the kind of data listed below.

```
SurveyDate    Rentaldate    outbound    inbound  vehiclesize  lolarate   kayrate
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         small       832        null
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         small    **855**       null
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         large       831        null
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         large    **851**       null
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         small       null       432
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         small       null     **455**
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         large       null       431
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         large       null     **451**
```

The ask it to grab the max value of all rows with the same vehicle size. For instance the output should look something like this:

```
SurveyDate    Rentaldate    outbound    inbound  vehiclesize  lolarate   kayrate
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         small    **855**       null
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         large    **851**       null
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         small       null     **455**
1/24/19        2/7/19         5          5         large       null     **451**
```

Below is the query that I put together to eliminate dups, let me know what you think about it:

```
select 
    SURVEY_DATE, 
    OUTBOUND, INBOUND, 
    MAX(lola_RATE) AS lola_SM,
    MAX(kay_RATE) AS kay_SM
from TABLE1
group by  OUTBOUND, INBOUND, SURVEY_DATE;
```

Comment: you keep not formatting your code

Comment: Sorry about that, I recenty learned how to format it, wont happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a good start, you just need to add all the non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT 
    SurveyDate, 
    Rentaldate, 
    outbound, 
    inbound, 
    vehiclesize,
    MAX(kayrate),
    MAX(lolarate)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY
    SurveyDate, 
    Rentaldate, 
    outbound, 
    inbound, 
    vehiclesize
```

Another option is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, without aggregation (this works if, as shown in your sample data, one of the two columns to aggregate is always `NULL`) :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY SurveyDate, Rentaldate, outbound, inbound, vehiclesize
            ORDER BY kayrate DESC, lolarate DESC
         ) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The results that you want a are a bit tricky.  `MAX()` as a window function may be the best approach:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MAX(kayrate) OVER (PARTITION BY SurveyDate, Rentaldate, outbound, inbound, vehiclesize) as max_kayrate,
             MAX(lolarate) OVER (PARTITION BY SurveyDate, Rentaldate, outbound, inbound, vehiclesize) as max_lolarate
      FROM t
     ) t
WHERE kayrate = max_kayrate OR
      lolarate = max_lolarate
```

Answer (score 0):

It's close. But now your query returns only one row:

```
SURVEYDATE RENTALDATE   OUTBOUND    INBOUND         LR         KR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1/24/19    2/7/19              5          5        855        455
```

If you add `vehiclesize` to the selected columns and in `group by` clause it will show:

```
SURVEYDATE RENTALDATE   OUTBOUND    INBOUND VEHICLESIZE         LR         KR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1/24/19    2/7/19              5          5 small              855        455
1/24/19    2/7/19              5          5 large              851        451
```

If you want to show null-columns separately you can use this conditional grouping:

```
select SurveyDate, Rentaldate, outbound, inbound, vehiclesize, 
       max(lolarate) lr, max(kayrate) kr
 from table1 
 group by 
       SurveyDate, Rentaldate, outbound, inbound, vehiclesize, 
       case when lolarate is null then 1 end,
       case when kayrate  is null then 1 end
```

<sup>**[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b48fbea8ce4f7c422b76311164a72d80)**</sup>

```
SURVEYDATE RENTALDATE   OUTBOUND    INBOUND VEHICLESIZE         LR         KR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1/24/19    2/7/19              5          5 small              855 
1/24/19    2/7/19              5          5 small                         455
1/24/19    2/7/19              5          5 large              851 
1/24/19    2/7/19              5          5 large                         451
```

Comment: incredibly helpful!